# ImportMember with ref parameter

Tags: c#, postsharp

How can I import an member into a PostSharp aspect if that member has a ref T parameter?

```
  [ImportMember("SetPropertyWithAoP", IsRequired = true)]
  public Func<object, object, string, bool> SetPropertyWithAoP;
```

upper code will work with member below

```
protected bool SetPropertyWithAoP(object storage, object value, string propertyName)
```

but will not work for that other member below due to ***ref*** and ***T generic*** parameter

```
protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
```

Comment: _"will not work"_ Is there an error reported?  If so, can you [edit] it into your question to aid future searchability?

Comment: Here below the compile time error: Error LA0075 Cannot bind field "...SetPropertyWithAoP" to type "...": cannot find a method "SetProperty(object, object, string) : bool" in type "..." or its ancestors.

Comment: Maybe you can use [this](http://support.sharpcrafters.com/discussions/questions/881-introduce-generic-interface)